SpringBoot.- send message with Carriage Return
I want to send a message with Carriage Return, with it send it as 1 line
public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {

    Properties prop = new Properties();

    prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
    prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.suerviciodecorreo.es");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "588");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.suerviciodecorreo.es");

   
    String mailTo = "ricaik@gmail.co";
    String from = "a098@cummmatica.co";
    String subject = "hola ? ";
    String body = "Saludos\\r\\n" +
            "\n" +
            " \n" +
            "\n" +
            " \n" +
            "\n" +
            "aaaaa\\r\\n" +
            "\n" +
            "bbbbbb\n" +
            "\n" ;

    //log.info("Sending email to: *{}* ", mailTo);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(prop, new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("a098@cummmatica.co", "Eiu8hhuy72024");
        }

    });

    //log.info("Sending email to1: " + mailTo);

    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("a098@cummmatica.co"));

    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(mailTo));
    message.setSubject(subject);

    MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    mimeBodyPart.setContent(body, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);


    log.info("Setting content");

    message.setContent(multipart);

    log.info("Sending message {} ", message);

    Transport.send(message);

    log.info("Sent message {}", message);

}


In Java, the sequence \\r\\n will be interpreted as a literal backslash followed by r and n, not as carriage return and line feed. You need to use \r\n directly in your string for the carriage return and line feed characters.
Here is the corrected version of your string:
String body = "Saludos\r\n" +
          "\n" +
          " \n" +
          "\n" +
          " \n" +
          "\n" +
          "aaaaa\r\n" +
          "\n" +
          "bbbbbb\n" +
          "\n";

Use \r\n for carriage return and line feed.
Use \n for a line feed (newline).

